# NodeJS project type is missing from PhpStorm

Tags: node.js, plugins, phpstorm

I am trying to setup Express.js project in PhpStorm IDE.

Here are things I've done:

1. Installed node and npm
2. Installed nodejs plugin in PhpStorm

When I try to create new project `node js express app` type is missing from the project list.

PhpStorm version: 10.0.0
OS: Windows 8

Comment: Please just download WebStorm...

Answer (score 0):

It's there for me:

[image]

Something must be wrong with NodeJS plugin (incompatible version, etc.). I'd suggest creating a support ticket